# Groups between a group and its profinite completion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $G$ and $H$ are finitely generated residually finite groups such that $G\leq H\leq \hat G$, where $\hat G$ denotes the profinite completion of $G$, does it follow that $$\hat H \cong \hat G$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By the universal property of profinite completions, we have to show that every homomorphism of groups $G \to K$, where $K$ is a profinite group, extends uniquely to a homomorphism of groups $H \to K$.

Well, we have only one choice: $G \to K$ corresponds to a homomorphism of profinite groups $\hat{G} \to K$, and this can be restricted to $H \leq \hat{G}$. This is clearly an extension of $G \to K$.

Now, assume that two homomorphism $f,g : H \to K$ agree on $G$. Then $\hat{f},\hat{g} : \hat{H} \to K$ are homomorphisms of profinite groups which agree on $\hat{G}$. Then they also agree on $H \leq \hat{G}$, i.e. $f=g$.

Comment: How is $\hat H$ inside $\hat G$?

Comment: You need the inclusion map from $G$ to $\hat H$ be continuous?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand your proof.

Comment: $G$ is discrete. And I've corrected the proof. Is it OK now?

Comment: G is not discrete, it has the profinite topology. By definition of profinite completion, you need the inclusion map from $G$ to $\hat H$ to be continuous. But I do not think it is the case always.

Comment: Ok, then please clarify the assumptions. I know profinite completions only for discrete groups.

Comment: Definition: A profinite completion  of $G$ is a tuple $(\hat G,\iota)$ where $\iota:G \rightarrow \hat G$ is

Comment: To show that $\hat H$ is isomorphic to $\hat G$ you are using universal property of completions. But you need to specify a continuous map from $G$ to $\hat H$ first. Look at the definition in Wilson's book section 1.4.

Comment: In fact if you take $\mathbb{Z}\leq \mathbb{Z}_2 \leq \hat \mathbb{Z}$ i think you get a counter example.